# Question IS relevant to server fault! Please remove hold and down votes

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Server Fault post: [Is it possible to run a Minecraft server on AWS Lambda?](https://serverfault.com/questions/872687/is-it-possible-to-run-a-minecraft-server-on-aws-lambda)

This question is *not* about end-user or domestic environments. I have now updated the question to explain this. Could the down votes and hold please be removed?

Comment: Also, this question appears to be domestic/consumer related, how is this one good any my question bad? If someone could explain I would be most grateful https://serverfault.com/questions/486500/should-i-put-the-os-of-a-game-server-minecraft-onto-an-ssd?rq=1

Comment: In short: I don't think it is, by todays standard (which has shifted over time).  Also, it is four years old.

Comment: Not sure that there really is a good place for Minecraft questions on StackExchange.  I find https://www.reddit.com/r/admincraft/ to be pretty good though.

Answer (score 9):

Really, Minecraft is the domain of hobbyists. Even if you would consider running a real business of hosting Minecraft servers, you would be much better suited to ask anything Minecraft-related on sites where this is inherently on-topic.

That said, you got an answer to your question "Can I run this on AWS Lambda" and the rest of it is extremely vague and broad anyway - we are not here to write tutorials or do beginners hand-holding about *any* topic.

Comment: Just thought it was a bit harsh. I did try to post it on the right Stack site but clearly got it wrong. Is there a Stack site where you can ask where a question should go? I keep getting tripped up by this problem!

Comment: [meta.se] is a generic meta site, but I am not sure if they allow this type of question. You can always ask on any sites meta to check if a particular question is welcome.

Comment: Will ask on the meta sites first then, thanks. I keep getting my rep hammered just because I misunderstand the definitions! Thanks again